# I'm facing aapt2 error in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm facing **aapt2** error in Android studio which states

> resource style/Theme.IAP not found (build manifest)

I didn't add anything like **Theme.IAPTheme** in `androidManifest.xml` or in `style.xml`. But why it shows that it was not found?. I cannot post photos right now.

So please see the image in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FMZfGdoUwjgqYErt0BNmCeRQFwFNzr9/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Have you tried using android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle properties.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Please help me

Comment: Can you please show me your Theme code, the theme id Theme.IAPTheme  Theme

Comment: I didn't added anything like Theme.IAPTheme in styles and Manifest File. But it shows in build/Manifest file (Theme.IAPTheme).

I'm new to this, so please help

Comment: Ok, then there are two solutions for your problem : 1. delete the the theme from your mainfest file or 2. you  need to to add a theme with the above name and there is a third solution where you can just change the theme.

Comment: Most likely that reference comes from an AndroidManifest from one of the libraries you have dependencies on. Check the merged manifest and post its contents (app/build/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml)